# All log files seemingly deleted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, log-files, ubuntu-16.04

I wanted to change to the log directory on ubuntu server, and check duplicity log, but I don't know what happened, it seems that all log files and sub-directories have gone missing! This is the command I used when I logged into the server:

```
sudo su | cd /var/log | cat duplicity.log | grep -i '. errors' | sort | uniq
```

I suppose I should have replaces first two pipes with `&&`. I have several questions, can I restore logs somehow? Will they continue to appear as they usually appear? Will deletion of all the log files create some server problems? Why did this happen?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that the files are deleted? Do you have a backup?

Comment: What's preventing you from looking on your system to see if the log files are still there or not?  Also, `sort | uniq` can be replaced with a simple [`sort -u`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Comment: @Sven @Adrew after I executed the command, I was in the `/var/log`. Then I executed `ls` and nothing was listed. I've logged out from the server, and logged in again, and cd-ed right into /var/log, and when I do `ls` again, it seems that all my logs are there. Strange. I don't know what happened.

Comment: @Liliane: After the program executed, you were not in `/var/log`.

Answer (score 5):

When piping commands together, each will be executed in its own shell. Subsequent programs will not inherit prior programs environment and thus, things like `cd` are not present anymore.

So, if you are in your home directory, say `/home/user` and execute `cd data | cat filename`, what happens is that you execute `cd data` and pipe the output (nothing in this case) to a new process with a new environment, which will still be in `/home/user` and not in `/data`, and thus won't find `filename` when trying to `cat` it.

A better option would be to just say `cat /var/log/duplicity.log` and not `cd`ing in the first place.

Even better: You don't need `cat` in the first place when using `grep`:

```
sudo grep -i ". errors" /var/log/duplicity.log | sort -u
```

should work like expected.